# How to insert boundfield values and template field value in gridview to database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

in the gridview control there are bound field and template field by clicking save button the gridview values should be saved in another table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPC3Q.png)
the gridview control

code tried  protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {

```
            String S_ID = row.Cells[0].Text;
            String Sub_Name = row.Cells[1].Text;
            String marks = (row.Cells[2].Text);
            String Semester = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text;




            String query = "insert into Marks(S_ID,Sub_Name,Semester,Marks) values(" + S_ID + ",'" + Sub_Name + "','" + Semester + "','" + marks + "')";
            String mycon = "Data Source=DESKTOP-HBMQHKE\\MSSQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=College;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mycon);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

error : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'mcl141'.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use parameters:

```cs
            String query = "insert into Marks(S_ID,Sub_Name,Semester,Marks) values(@S_ID, @Sub_Name, @Semester, @marks)";
            String mycon = "Data Source=DESKTOP-HBMQHKE\\MSSQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=College;Integrated Security=True";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mycon))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S_ID", S_ID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sub_Name", Sub_Name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Semester", Semester);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@marks", marks);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```